# How to hide rows in material table based on a value in data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have an array of data being displayed in a material-table.  My data has a field called `Active` and its value can be either 0 or 1.  If the `Active` value is 0, then that object is inactive.  If `Active` is one, the object is active.

I want the user to have the ability to check a checkbox in the table toolbar and hide all inactive data.

I am using `@material-ui/core` for my UI components.

If the checkbox is checked/true, then the data where the Active field is 0 are hidden.  If the checkbox unchecked/false, then all of the data in the array is displayed.

```
    const [intakes, setIntakes] = useState([]);

    function IntakeList() {
        const CustomToolbarComponent = (props) => {
            return (
                <div
                    style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        justifyContent: "flex-end",
                        alignItems: "center",
                    }}
                >
                    <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox />} label="Hide inactive objects" />
                    <div>
                        <MTableToolbar {...props} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        };

        return (
            <MaterialTable
                title=""
                data={intakes.intakes}
                columns={columns}
                components={{
                    Toolbar: (props) => <CustomToolbarComponent {...props} />,
                }}
            />
        );
    }
```

Here is a short example of my JSON:

```
{
  "intakes": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Active": 0
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "Active": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: u can use a state to save the user's preference (whether he wants to see the inactive rows) `const [showInactive, setShowInactive] = useState(false)`. Now u simply has to set the `data={showInactive ?  intakes.intakes : intakes.intakes.filter(x=> x.Active === 1 ) }`

Comment: This implementation results in the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')`

Comment: can u please create codesandbox and share the link here

Comment: Apologies for the late reply.  Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-orla-wz0zm0?file=/src/App.js
The issue with the filter is no longer occurring.  The checkbox does not function as expected.  By default, the checkbox is true.  This means that the data with Active: 0 should be hidden from the table.  The opposite is happening.  When `showInactive` is true, data with Active: 0 must be hidden.  When `showInactive` is false, ALL data is shown in the table